# Allowing remote connection to mysql docker by root user in docker-compose file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Currently  I am using below simple yaml to get a mysqsl server going

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'strongpasswordnobodycanguessorcrackatall'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'somethingevenmorestrongerthaneverbefore'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - compose-my-db
volumes:
  - ./:compose-my-db:
```

However I have to then attach to the container and use :
 `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'c'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Which effectively gives me all the privileges I need and allows remote connection to the users I have created in the compose file.

I am aware that I can modify the my.cnf or add init script that runs after mysqld has initialized but I wish for it
However I would like the user I create in the Docker-Compose

Answer (score 1):

I think we can achieve this via `MYSQL_INITDB` - where we can set an initialization script inside the MySQL container.

first, you can add an env variable for MYSQL_INITDB like below

```
      MYSQL_INITDB: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01.sql
```

then, you need to update your volume configuration as below

```
volumes:
  - ./compose-my-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Create a 01.sql in the same directory of your docker-compose file.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'c'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Check the official documentation here : https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
under **Initializing a fresh instance** sub-topic.